# LibFm Recommender system

Tags: dictionary

How can I use the map(mean average precision) to evaluate LibFm ( http://www.libfm.org/)?

i run this code with

`./libFM -task c -train trainfrappe.csv.libfm -test testfrappe.csv.libfm -dim '1,1,8' -iter 5000 -out result.txt`

Comment: Have you tried using [scikit-learn's MAP metric](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.average_precision_score.html)

Comment: Did you mean using a learning method? libFM allows you to use four learning methods-SGD, SGDA, ALS and MCMC Ref:http://www.libfm.org/libfm-1.42.manual.pdf